# The equivalent of Echo web framework for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a framewok that can provide an abstract GUI model (in ruby) on top of html/js/css. There are several frameworks such as Echo that do this for Java. Are there any for rails out there?

Comment: [bowline](https://github.com/maccman/bowline) should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I don't think there is an equivalence for Echo.

There is [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) which is a Javascript library made for building RIA, but it's not tightly coupled with Rails like Echo with Java.

Answer (score 0):

http://bowlineapp.com/ sounds like it could be a match. Can't say for sure since I don't know Echo.